# summarize returning same value to all rows

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I am trying to agregate daily data from brazilian Central Bank into monthly data, using rbcb package:

```
selic <- get_series(432, start_date = '2001-12-03', end_date = '2023-02-01')
nomes <- c("mes","selic")
colnames(selic) <- nomes
selic$meses <- floor_date(selic$mes)
m_selic <- selic %>% 
    group_by(meses) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(selic)) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
```

The problem is that I get the same value to all rows:

```
head(m_selic):
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  meses               `mean(selic)`
  <dttm>                      <dbl>
1 2001-12-03 00:00:00            19
2 2001-12-04 00:00:00            19
3 2001-12-05 00:00:00            19
4 2001-12-06 00:00:00            19
5 2001-12-07 00:00:00            19
6 2001-12-08 00:00:00            19
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong:

on

```
selic$meses <- floor_date(selic$mes)
```

was missing an argument:

```
selic$meses <- floor_date(selic$mes,'month')
```